Azure Logic Apps with Form Recognizer - Get Array definition in optional settings entry
I created an Azure Logic App using Form Recognizer to analyze PDF based invoice files. I actually recognized that the process is working well, but in encountering issues in enabling the barcode option. I always receive "Enter a valid array" when i put this option into the form.

Does anyone know what value i have to insert in that field?
Thanks folks!
I already tried to add the following into the field:

["Barcodes"]

Expression: items('For_each')?['fields']?['Barcodes']?['value']

Expression: items('For_each')?['fields']?['Barcodes']


None of the above worked. Returned always NULL/Empty

To solve the issue use below design:
In Standard Plan:

In compose give value barcodes.
Then:

Output:

In Consumption Plan:
You can directly use the value as below:

Output:


Thanks for your suggestion. I applied your solution to work with the Compose component as i am working with the Standard Plan. It seems to work as the additional Options to include Barcodes now delivers the output to the next components where i can parse the details.
